# Getting unmatched router for password_expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

```
Rails 3.2
Devise
devise_security_extension
rails_email_validator
```

I followed the instructions for both Devise and devise_security_extensions.

In my views/user/password_expired/show.html.slim, I have:

```
- content_for :page_header do
     = t('users.passwords.create_password')
   = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: [resource_name, :password_expired], html: {method: :post, class: "form-horizontal new_user"}) do |f|
     .form-horizontal-column.wide
       .form-group
         = devise_error_messages!
       .form-group style="width: 600px"
         = f.label :current_password, t('users.passwords.current_password')
         = f.password_field :current_password
       .form-group style="width: 600px"
         = f.label :password, t('users.passwords.new_pass')
         = f.password_field :password
       .form-group style="width: 600px"
         = f.label :password_confirmation, t('users.passwords.confirm_new_password')
         = f.password_field :password_confirmation
       .form-group
         = f.submit t('users.passwords.change_my_password'), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg"
```

When I run the application, the above view is displayed, and when I enter the old password, new password, and confirmation, and submit, the form re-displays. The log file tells me:

```
Processing by ApplicationController#routing_error as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NngH6IQdF2uPOziO9j4r59Lf4Gd2sTF8xxwh0OUqDOI=", "user"=>{"current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Change My Password", "unmatched_route"=>"users/password_expired"}
```

Shouldn't this route be handled by Devise? Any ideas how to fix it?

## SOLUTION:

Change the call to put, instead of post, so the view will look like:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: [resource_name, :password_expired], html: {method: :put, class: "form-horizontal new_user"}) do |f|
```

Comment: can you add the output of `rails routes`?

Comment: I use doing a POST, instead of a PUT. I changed it to PUT and it's now working

Comment: cool, add it as an answer, to help others, not just as an edit

Comment: Done, posted an asnwer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the route calls for a put, not a post. Change the call to put, instead of post, so the view will look like:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: [resource_name, :password_expired], html: {method: :put, class: "form-horizontal new_user"}) do |f|
```

This works